# How to specify what database django should use when aauthenticating a user?

Tags: python, database, django

I figured out how to get  the User created in a secondary database but I can't figure out what I should use in order to get the database to use the secondary database instead of the default database when looking if a User exists and then can be authenticated.

Say I have:

```
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
```

how do i tell django to use a database named secondary instead of using the default database?

Also, I assume that these follow along the same methods but how would i use login() or logout() by using the secondary database as well.

Comment: using the default ModelBackend, I assume?

Answer (score 1):

authenticate only takes credentials and is a shortcut to calling authenticate on your backends until you get a user:

[https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/**init**.py#L39](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py#L39)

Assuming you are using the default backend ( https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/backends.py#L4 ), there is no way to use this backend and select the non-default database, I think.

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend

class NonDefaultModelBackend(ModelBackend):
    """
    Authenticates against django.contrib.auth.models.User.
    Using SOMEOTHER db rather than the default
    """
    supports_inactive_user = True

    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        try:
            user = User.objects.using("SOMEOTHER").get(username=username)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.using("SOMEOTHER").get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

I think this will give you the same behavior as the default backend but with the non-default db. Then you can add your backend to the settings or replace the default backend outright.

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'path.to.mybackends.NonDefaultModelBackend', 
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',)
```

or so.

Comment: right but then with login() or logout() how does that work? As i look through django\contrib\auth I come across the login form in the views.py file. but there isn't a place where you can throw in a .using(databasename) in the login form.

Comment: `login()` will work with the new backend b/c `AuthenticationForm` will work with the new backend because `authenticate()` will work with the new backend it looks to me.

Comment: `password_reset_confirm` looks to be the only place in views that is hardcoded to the default db.  As for the convenience forms, it looks like `UserCreationForm` and `PasswordResetForm` would need to be overridden to use the non-default db.